# Pager previous / next semantics

Tags: html, pagination, semantics

The following is my code for comments pagination.

```
<ul class="pager">
  <li class="previous">
    <a href="#">Older Comments &larr;</a>
  </li>
  <li class="next">
    <a href="#">Newer Comments &rarr;</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

My problem is if I'm on the first page of comments (and older comments link is hidden), an empty list item is displayed in the DOM.

```
<li class="previous">
</li>
<li class="next">
  <a href="#">Newer Comments &rarr;</a>
</li>
```

In a semantic way should I remove the empty list item (1) or leave it there empty (2)?

### 1/

```
<ul class="pager">
  <li class="next">
    <a href="#">Newer Comments &rarr;</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

### 2/

```
<ul class="pager">
  <li class="previous">
  </li>
  <li class="next">
    <a href="#">Newer Comments &rarr;</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Which option is correct in a semantic way?

Answer (score 7):

I have a better suggestion to use a disabled state:

```
<ul class="pager">
  <li class="previous">
    <a href="#" class="disabled">Older Comments &larr;</a>
  </li>
  <li class="next">
    <a href="#">Newer Comments &rarr;</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

#### Attempt 2

Also I have another idea, if you are completely getting rid of CSS. Instead of `<a>` tags, you can use `<button>` or `<input type="button" />`, as even in Facebook, the same thing is used. So, you can style the `<button>` tag to look like `<a>` tag and give a disabled state, as this works even when both JavaScript and CSS is disabled.

```
<ul class="pager">
  <li class="previous">
    <button disabled="disabled">Older Comments &larr;</button>
  </li>
  <li class="next">
    <button>Newer Comments &rarr;</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

For styling `<button>` as `<a>`:

```css
/* Just for this demo */
ul, li {margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; display: inline-block;}

button {border: none; background: none; color: #00f; text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer;}
button:disabled {color: #999; cursor: default;}
```

```html
<ul class="pager">
  <li class="previous">
    <button disabled="disabled">Older Comments &larr;</button>
  </li>
  <li class="next">
    <button>Newer Comments &rarr;</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The above code works in all browsers, including Internet Explorer! `:)`

Comment: This seems like the most semantic approach.  All the data is there and however you interpret a disabled link is entirely up to the front end.  If you remove the item entirely via the backend, you have no choice in styling to indicate that there are no older comments to view; but with this approach you have the option to either hide (with CSS) or change the style of the link.  I think Praveen Kumar's answer better separates the styling and the markup out of the three options.

Comment: @JosephMarikle Added more details. A different approach. Thanks for your input. `:)`

Comment: This is great, but how can I pass a URL to the prev/next button? If I understand it correctly, **if there are no previous comments (prev)**, then I should use `button` instead of `a` with disabled state, and **if there are more comments (next)**, then I should use `a` instead of `button` with a href attribute for the next comments page? Please explain it further. MDN says than I can't put phrasing content inside button, thus I can't use: `<button><a></a></button>`.

Comment: @RafcioKowalsky You don't need to use an `<a>` at all. We can use the `onclick='location.href=""'` kind of stuff. Also, why do you need to use `<a></a>` inside `<button>`?

Comment: Just a friendly dissenting opinion, but I feel that the semantics of disabled is not clear.  Using semantically correct HTML is not directly for the user reading the page.  If you really feel that your users can't understand the absence of a previous link, then I think you should indicate it in an explicit and semantic manner with some text, but I highly question whether that is necessary. Also, if using buttons, what if javascript is disabled?

Comment: @peterjb We can use `title` to give them a tooltip, which is not affected by the CSS and also it is accessible via screen readers for what they are. `:)` Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

**here's short and sweet.. :)**

```html
<style type="text/css">
a.disabled {
   pointer-events: none;
   cursor: default;
   color:#999;
}
</style>
<ul class="pager">
  <li class="previous">
    <a class="disabled" href="#">Older Comments &larr;</a>
  </li>
  <li class="next">
    <a href="#">Newer Comments &rarr;</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

GOOD LUCK!

Comment: Simple question. What happens when CSS is disabled? I ask this because, this question relates to Semantics.

Comment: @PraveenKumar I agree with you here :)

Comment: @Praveen Kumar if user wants great experience, he never disable css. :D

Comment: Leave the user buddy, what if the company or the computer doesn't allow or support? @VarunaLex?

Answer (score 0):

My personal opinion on something like this is to not use markup for stuff that isn't there.  No disabled buttons or links or empty list items.  When you are on the first page, there is no previous page, so there should be no markup for the previous page. If you want to leave space for the previous page link, just use CSS.

Also, if I'm being a stickler, there's no reason for there to be a `<ul>` if there's only one link, and you might consider using an `<ol>` when you have both links because there is an order to the links.

If you're able to alter the template for the page 1 case, I would suggest just a simple:

```
<div class="next">
    <a href="nextlink">next page</a>
</div>
```

Also, I recommend not requiring javascript for navigation.  Normal html links are appropriate here.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have a previous link, this is just fine.

```
<ul class="pager">
  <li class="next">
    <a href="#">Newer Comments &rarr;</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The only reason people add some markup for something **that isn't there** is only for user experience, so that the user does not get confused when a button / link they were expecting to be there isn't there anymore. That is the sole purpose of a disabled element.

joke: after years of therapy I can finally understand that the button that is grayed out does nothing, and is not there just to taunt me. *begone* !

Examples where markup is not necessary:

- you use positioning in your css,
- showing a disabled button would be awkward

  - e.g. `previous` button should not appear on the first slide of a presentation?
  - e.g. `continue` button should/may not appear in a videogame unless you have a save file?

Answer (score 0):

You can also implement this where the `a` element **doesn't have** a `href`. That way it is not rendered as a link. And it is easy to style it differently then when it has a `href`.

The [HTML5 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element) says the following about the `a` element:

> If the `a` element has no `href` attribute, then the element represents a placeholder for where a link might otherwise have been placed, if it had been relevant.

For good semantics, you should also surround your component with a `nav` element, and use `rel="prev"` and `rel="next"` on your links.

```css
.pagination a:not([href]){
  color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<nav class="pagination">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a rel="prev">Older Comments &larr;</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" rel="next">Newer Comments &rarr;</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```